# What can be best delay for change carousel slide?

Tags: experience

I want to know, what would be best delay time to change slides in carousel.

Comment: [http://shouldiuseacarousel.com/](http://shouldiuseacarousel.com/) tends to have good information about carousel use.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey I don't disagree with you, but remember that the OP asked about best practice with carousels, not whether or not he should use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:** 5 - 10 seconds

**Long Answer:** This totally depends on the content. Is there a lot of text for the user to read? If so, you need to give the user enough time to process all of the information. If it is just an image, you can get away with going through the slides more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

## Just don't

As Evil Closet Monkey astutely points out in the comments, your goals probably won't be answered by a carousel. In fact, the time-delayed slider solves almost zero real business needs.

Think of it this way: The content is either worth putting on the page or not.

## If you must

Anything after the first slide might as well not be there. Chances are, every slide after the first is just there to appease someone's misguided agenda.

> Carousels are effective at being able to tell people in Marketing/Senior Management that their latest idea is on the Home Page. —*Lee Duddell*

So design around that problem. Set the delay to the maximum duration you can get away with before the executive in question complains. 5-6 seconds should do. Then your users never have to be bothered by it but executives feel validated.

## Manual control

On the off chance that the additional content has some value, include paging controls. This gives the rare curious user who has the patience to look around the chance to see more content exactly when they want it. Once a user manually controls the slideshow, *turn off the auto-play script*.

Answer (score 1):

The carousel is made to draw the user's attention to something important.

> When the carousel rotates too quickly users don’t have enough time to
>   investigate interesting slides. This can make users feel uneasy as
>   they try to rush through the slide’s text before it rotates. Of course
>   auto-rotating too slowly will have the opposite effect, with users
>   getting bored by slides that are of little interest to them.
>
> The amount of text in each slide has a significant say in the duration
>   a slide should be shown. If there’s just a short header, 5-7 seconds
>   proved appropriate during test, while longer durations were needed for
>   more text-heavy slides.

You can see more here:

Here you can find guidelines for good carousel design: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/designing-effective-carousels/

And here about the carousel's time: https://baymard.com/blog/homepage-carousel

I hope it helps.

Comment: The key takeaway from that NN/g piece is "*A static hero or integrating content in the UI may be better solutions. But if a carousel is your hero, good navigation and content can help make it effective.*" IOW, you should probably use a better solution 

Comment: @plainclothes I did the research and you're right, many designers do not like the carousels and find them flawed, and I agree with the motives. But in some cases it may be a good option, for example, products on e-commerce sites, related videos of youtube (although it has manual control) or photos of a portfolio, which the person is clicking to see more in sequence. :)

Comment: For the record, it's not typically "designers" that don't like auto-sliders, it's the usability and conversion teams.